# How can I get bash command line completion to complete a partial argument and then provide more hints

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, shell-script

Imagine I have a command 'command' which takes arguments foo:bar foo:foo bar:bar or bar:foo
I can write a command line completion script that I can source into my environment to give me completion that looks like the following:

```
function _command_opt()
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="foo:bar foo:foo bar:bar bar:foo"
    if [[ ${prev: -7} == 'command' ]]
    then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}"  -- ${cur}) );
        return 0;
    fi
}
complete -F _command_opt -o bashdefault -o default 'command'
```

However if I type `command f[tab][tab]` I get foo:bar and foo:foo listed, but neither is completed onto my command line (because they aren't yet distinct.  What I would like to accomplish is that this produces `command foo:` and leaves my cursor at the end of the current word (rather than adding a space) to allow me to then type `b` or `f` and then tab again to finish the command.  The example problem is just to show what I mean... the real case the prefix:suffix combinations are quite long, so partial completion would be really beneficial. e.g. 25 different commands that all begin with prefix translationupdateprocess: and translationupdateprocess is one of 25 different equally long prefixs with that many options.

Does anyone know of a way to get bash complete to operate this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code (I replaced your options with `foo:baz foo:qux bar:eat bar:egg` in order to clarify):

```
function _command_opt()
{
  local cur cursec command opts
  COMPREPLY=()

  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  cursec=`echo ${cur} | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'`;

  command="${COMP_WORDS[1]}"
  opts="foo bar"

  case "${command}" in
    foo)
      COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "baz qux" -- ${cursec}) ); return 0;;
    bar)
      COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "eat egg" -- ${cursec}) ); return 0;;
    *) ;;
  esac

  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -S ":" -- ${cur}) ); compopt -o nospace;
}

complete -F _command_opt -o bashdefault -o default 'command'
```

When you type `command`<kbd>tab</kbd> you can get the first level list `foo: bar:` and when you type `f`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> you get the completion list for the second level `baz qux`. Then, you can type `q`<kbd>tab</kbd> to get the full command line `command foo:qux`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry it took me a while to get back to this.  Great answer.  Thanks!